# Cast receives a APPLICATION_NOT_FOUND status when trying to launch an application

Tags: android, chromecast

```
            Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient, "XXX", false)
                        .setResultCallback(
                            new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult result) {
                                Status status = result.getStatus();
                                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                    ApplicationMetadata applicationMetadata =
                                            result.getApplicationMetadata();
                                    String sessionId = result.getSessionId();
                                    String applicationStatus = result.getApplicationStatus();
                                    boolean wasLaunched = result.getWasLaunched();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("Status-Cast", String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()));
                                    teardown();
                                }
                            }
                            });
```

I am trying to get a test chrome cast app working but I keep getting a APPLICATION_NOT_FOUND error (2004).  I have check my application ID and I can access the url in my browser.  It is an unpublished app which I am testing on my device that is registered on the dev console.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, this occurs when you haven't [x] send your serial # to Google on your device, haven't registered your device in the developer console, or you haven't restarted your Chromecast device 20 minutes after you changed something in the developers console.

Comment: Takes 15 minutes to register device. 6 hours to propagate something else, and power cycle the chromecast to clear its cache :-)

Comment: 15 min to register, hence my saying 20 is safe.  The 6 hours is if you don't power cycle your device.  And that was for the preview SDK.  It's different for the current one.

Comment: Thanks I had added my device but not checked a setting on the chrome cast Android app

Comment: I have the same problem however my status is 15 - TIMEOUT. What can be the reason here?